# Angular 6 - Unit testing a subscribe function in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to unit test the subscribe function of this service. And looking at the code coverage report generated by istanbul, I can see that this code is not covered.

## Code

### layout.component.ts

```
import {Component, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutService } from './layout.service';

import { some } from 'lodash';

@Component({
    selector: 'cgm-layout',
    templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss'],
    providers: [LayoutService]
})
class LayoutComponent {

    message: any;

    constructor(
        private service: LayoutService
    ) {
        service.messagePublished$.subscribe(
            message => {
                this.setMessage(message);
            }
        );
    }

    setMessage(message): void {
        this.message = message;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.message = null;
        }, 7000);
    }

}

export {
    LayoutComponent
};
```

This is my Unit Test

### layout.component.spec.ts

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { LayoutService } from './layout.service';

describe('LayoutComponent', () => {
    let component: LayoutComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LayoutComponent>;
    let service;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        service = new LayoutService();
        mockLayoutService = jasmine.createSpyObj('LayoutService', ['messagePublished$']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                LayoutComponent,

            ],
            providers: [
                LayoutService
            ],
            schemas: [
                NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LayoutComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        component.message = 'Garbage';
    });

    it('should call messagePublished', () => {
        spyOn(service.messagePublished$, 'subscribe');
        TestBed.createComponent(LayoutComponent);

        expect(service.messagePublished$.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    describe('setMessage', () => {

        it('should set the Message', fakeAsync(() => {
            component.setMessage('Message');

            expect(component.message).toBe('Message');
            tick(7000);
            expect(component.message).toBeNull();
        }));

    });
});
```

So the code never seems to go over the 'service.messagePublished$.subscribe' part. Here is the [code coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRZMm.jpg).

The error I'm getting is 'Expected spy subscribe to have been called', which I'm guessing is the error you get when that code block is not covered.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise you to move your subscription from the constructor to an `ngOnInit`. Angular created several lifecycle hooks which get called when a component get's created (ngOnInit) and other when data changes or when it gets destroyed - see [Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

This way you can test your code by calling the `ngOnInit()` method.

In case you cannot change the code you can try creating a component instance and check if your method was called like in pseudo-code below:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { LayoutService } from './layout.service';

describe('LayoutComponent', () => {
    let component: LayoutComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LayoutComponent>;
    let serviceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<LayoutService>;;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const spy = spyOn(service.messagePublished$, 'subscribe')
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                LayoutComponent,

            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: LayoutService, useValue: spy }
            ],
            schemas: [
                NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
            serviceSpy = TestBed.get(ValueService);
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LayoutComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        component.message = 'Garbage';
    });

    it('should call messagePublished', () => {
        TestBed.createComponent(LayoutComponent);

        expect(service.messagePublished$.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm only in charge of unit testing right now. So I can't really change the code. I have to figure out a way to access the code when it's in the constructor.

Comment: Updated the code for testing constructor tests. Hopefully it should give you an idea to how to check if the code has been run.

Comment: It is because you replace your LayoutService with a mock in this line: `provide: LayoutService, useValue: mockLayoutService` and mockLayoutService doesn't have a property of messagePublished$. mockLayoutService needs to be an object with a property messagePublished$ which has a subscribe property.

Comment: Code updated. I hope it gives you a clearer picture.

Comment: To insantiate your service replace service = new LayoutService(); with service = TestBed.get(LayoutService); after the configureTestingModule() method

Comment: Even then, I get the same error that spy subscribe hasn't been called.

Comment: I've updated my answer, why do you have 2 beforeEach()?

Comment: 2 beforeEach() blocks comes build in when you create an Angular project using angular-cli. I just work off of the skeleton created with it. I use one beforeEach with the async directive to configure the TestBed and the other to set my initial values before testing.

Comment: Did my answer help you?